# Change xml attribute in foreach statement c#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to save XML-attribute value in a database, using information if checkbox is checked. If checkbox is checked, the attribute value is "TRUE", otherwise it's false. When I use foreach statement, the last enumerated value is usually assigned.

Here is the part of my code:

```
XmlAttribute xmlAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("BooleanValue");
foreach (string value in list) //list is a List<object>
{
    XmlNode xmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "VALUE", "");
    if (checkBox1.Checked || 
        checkBox2.Checked ||
        checkBox3.Checked)
    xmlAttribute.Value = "TRUE";

    if (!checkBox1.Checked || 
        !checkBox2.Checked ||
        !checkBox3.Checked)
     xmlAttribute.Value = "FALSE";

    xmlNode.Attributes.Append(xmlAttribute);
    xmlNode.InnerText = val;
    childNode.AppendChild(xmlNode);
}
```

When I run my application, I get an XML attribute *xmlAttribute* "FALSE" value anyway.

What I need to have:
I need to have the following XML:

```
<ROOT><NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="TRUE">Value 1</VALUE></NODE>
      <NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="TRUE">Value 2</VALUE></NODE>
      <NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="FALSE">Value 3</VALUE></NODE>
      <NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="FALSE">Value 4</VALUE></NODE>
      <NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="TRUE">Value 5</VALUE></NODE>
      <NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="FALSE">Value 6</VALUE></NODE>
</ROOT>
```

What I actually get:

```
<ROOT><NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="FALSE">Value 1</VALUE></NODE>
      <NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="FALSE">Value 2</VALUE></NODE>
      <NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="FALSE">Value 3</VALUE></NODE>
      <NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="FALSE">Value 4</VALUE></NODE>
      <NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="FALSE">Value 5</VALUE></NODE>
      <NODE><VALUE ATTRIBUTE="FALSE">Value 6</VALUE></NODE>
</ROOT>
```

Because in C# *FALSE* value is stayed at last position in foreach loop

The question is: how do I do to assign the correct values of my attribute. Thanks

Comment: Are you saving the file after modifying?

Comment: No. XML is saved into database field

Comment: I still think it's a Boolean logic issue, if any of your check boxes are unchecked you will never return any but false. Same if you use ELSE or ELSE IF.

Answer (score 3):

I think your boolean logic is wrong. You currently have

```
If any are checked  
   mark True  
If any are unchecked  
   mark False
```

I'd say you probably want to use an `else` after the first `if` instead of writing a new condition.

Comment: I tried to use "else" instead of "if" statement. Also, I tried to use switch-case statement. So, the problem stayed the same

Comment: @user1913479 I think then your problem statement is unclear. What behavior are you expecting? Can you show us an example of the XML you WANT and the XML you are GETTING?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (checkBox1.Checked || 
        checkBox2.Checked ||
        checkBox3.Checked)
    xmlAttribute.Value = "TRUE";

    if (!checkBox1.Checked || 
        !checkBox2.Checked ||
        !checkBox3.Checked)
     xmlAttribute.Value = "FALSE";
```

So you get TRUE if any one of the boxes are checked and then overwrite it with FALSE if any one of them are not checked. i.e. you've ended up with

```
if (checkBox1.Checked && 
        checkBox2.Checked &&
        checkBox3.Checked)
    xmlAttribute.Value = "TRUE"
else
    xmlAttribute.Value = "FALSE"
```

I'm takimng a wild guess at this not being what you wanted